# Buffer length smaller than expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I'm creating a Buffer from a long string of hex but getting some size mismatching (when I try to decrypt it). Sure enough when I run the following code:

```
var hexData = fs.readFileSync(fileName).toString().trim();
var bufferData = new Buffer(hexData, 'hex');

console.log(Buffer.byteLength(hexData, 'hex'));
console.log(bufferData.length);
```

my output is:

> 232548
>
> 30

Why is the whole string not being loaded into the Buffer?

EDIT: I noticed I was being silly and should be doing

```
var bufferData = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'hex');
```

But the length of *that* is `930194`!

Comment: You load the file content into a variable hexData, but use the variable data to build the buffer.

Comment: Sorry, typo in my rewriting the variable names for SO.

Comment: So, then it's a very good question. And the given answer could save a lot of time to develpers having a simillar problem. Therefor uv for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant `hexData` and not `data` when you build `bufferData`, `Buffer.byteLength` seems to happily accept malformed hex, whereas the `Buffer` constructor will strip it out of the buffer. Consider:

```
> Buffer.byteLength('ff00junk', 'hex')
4
> var b = new Buffer('ff00junk', 'hex')
> b.length
2
> b
<Buffer ff 00>
```

Perhaps your file contains invalid hex?

Comment: Actually, you're right! There are linebreaks! The buffer is qutting after the first one, so that's why its 30 and why my correct implementation gets the correct number!

Comment: And you can do a string replace on the input string, deleting anything other than `[0-9a-fA-F]`! Brilliant!